# can lm_sensors still damage hardware?

Tags: server, hardware, monitoring, support, lm-sensors

I just ran lm_sensors and foolishly typed YES to everything.. This is a brand new PC I've built and I'm worried I've damaged something now. Then I read that it can overwrite EEPROM and damage hardware from probing i2c. This is a recent desktop chipset based on Intel series 300 (b360) with an i3-8100.

Is lm_sensors still a risk? I'm kinda freaking out here, how would I even know if something was damaged?

Comment: If your terminal window is still open, please scroll back, select and copy what you did and [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1116665/edit) that into the question, so we see what lm_sensors detected and what you did. (please format as "code" to preserve the layout)

Comment: It isn't open anymore, and I purged lm_sensors.  I didn't get any errors or panics etc, but I did get the default warnings that I opted "yes" to. What should I do?